# onclick prepare html when ajax response arrivers and render in react?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

Hey I'm new is react my requirement is that when a user clicks on a button an ajax get request get fired to the 
server and based of receieved response I have to prepare the html and display it.
below is my code it is not working .. it can be solved in jquery by using `async: false` but i don't have to use that
any idea how to solve using axios

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios"

class UserItems extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    useritem: ''
  }
} 

prepareHtmlOnAjaxResponse(){

  var user_item = this.state.useritem
  // html prepation done here
  return preparedHtml;
}


getDatFromServeronclick() {

  // getting user data from server is done in this function 
  // when data is receieved it is stored in a state
    var self = this;
    var promise = axios.get("http://localhost:4000/user/1/items.json")
    promise.then(function (response) {
    self.setState({ useritem: response.data.items })
     self.prepareHtmlOnAjaxResponse()  // prepare html 
    })
console.log("executing first and returning null")
}


render() {
   var result = this.getDatFromServeronclick()  // getting undefined value this has to be called onclick
    return (
       <div> 
        {result}  / result is undefined
      </div>

    );
}


 }

export default UserItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `self.setState function` instead of `self.state assignment`, otherwise React wouldn't trigger rerender of the component.

```
var promise = axios.get("http://localhost:4000/user/1/items.json")
    promise.then(function (response) {
    self.setState({ useritems: response.data.items })
})
```

From React's [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

**NEVER mutate this.state directly**, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

---

Then in your `render` function

```
<button onClick={() => this.getDatFromServeronclick() }> {this.state.useritems.map(user => user.title)} </button>
```

you can replace `user.title` with whatever `keys` your `object useritems` has.

Comment: I have updated the code but how to display html from `prepareHtmlOnAjaxResponse` function

Comment: see my updated answer or create a jsfiddle and I can correct it. please rename useritem to useritems also